# Probability based on average/historical data

Tags: probability, inference

I have ten years of data, which I have averaged. Is it possible to calculate the probability that a future point will be less than a threshold based on my data?

For example, say the average is 0.065. How can I calculate the probability P that a future data point will be less than 0.1? I am looking at daily data points, where each day is an average of the daily data for the previous ten years.

I understand I may need something other than the average, like a distribution or something, but I do not know what that is. Depending on how specific an answer is, I can look up equations and formulas.

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen n/N where n is 0.1 and N is 10, wondering if there is anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your assumption is that the **actual model is**:
$$Y_i=\beta_i+\epsilon_i$$

Your estimator for $\beta$ is given by (which is also the OLS estimate):

$$\hat \beta= \sum Y_i/N$$

Now the variance of $\hat \beta$ is:

$$var(\hat \beta) = var(\sum \frac {Y_i}{N})=\frac{1}{N^2}var(\sum Y_i)=\frac{1}{N^2}var(\sum \epsilon_i)$$

At this point, we usually assume that the **$\epsilon_i$ is IID and mean 0**, then:

$$var(\hat\beta)=\frac {1}{N}var(\epsilon_i)$$

Now we estimate the variance for $\epsilon_i$, the MSE is good estimate for this. To get the variance of $Y_0-\hat Y_0$ we also need to add the variance of error, thus:

$$var(Y_0-\hat Y_0) = var(\hat \beta + \epsilon)= \frac {MSE}{N}+MSE$$

Now we need to assume what distribution the error has. **Standard assumption is that it is normal**. Then the confidence interval is given by:

$$\hat Y_0+/-t_{1-\frac{a}{2},n-1}\sqrt {\frac{MSE}{N}+MSE}$$

The t-distribution stems from the fact that the MSE's are estimates.

Similarly, when using OLS you can calculate the interval for (almost) any model by:

$$\hat Y_0 +/- t_{1-\frac{a}{2},n-p }\sqrt{MSE(1+X_0'(X'X)^{-1}X_0}$$

Comment: I like how detailed this model is, but I have absolutely no idea how to implement it. I've have a very rudimentary introduction to statistics, which led me to the idea that I should use statistics to model my data. Can this all be boiled down to a descriptive term or equation (like "Randolph's Function")? Or, more detail to help me better understand this answer.

Comment: @user1187621 Yes, just estimate any sort of curve on the data and IF the assumptions hold, the final equation outputs the correct confidence interval. That means you can be $a$% certain that the observation falls within the interval. However, given that the model is a bit silly, it's probably better to use some forecasting package and just use the forecast error it reports... (Normally you would probably want to have ARMA terms in the model and boostrap rather than the normal distribution assumption).

Comment: So I could use an empirical distribution function or Poisson-type, then plug in for the final equation to get the confidence. Correct?

Comment: @user1187621 Poisson type would not work without adjustments, since its mean is not zero. Empirical distribution or bootstrapping would work. But the final equation is only for Gaussian distribution, however it's easy to see what the variance is from that too.